# Java GSON check data

Tags: java, gson

I'm having trouble with gson:

For example I have this output from website:

`[["connected"], ["user1":"Hello"], ["user2":"Hey"], ["disconnected"]]`

But I want parse this JSON and output something like this:

```
connected
user1 says: Hello
user2 says: Hey
disconnected
```

I quicly wrote this code:

```
public static void PrintEvents(String id){
    String response = Post.getResponse(Server()+"events?id="+id,"");
    // response is [["connected"],["user1":"Hello"],["user2":"Hey"],["disconnected"]]

    JsonElement parse = (new JsonParser()).parse(response); //found this in internet

    int bound = ????????????; // Should be 4

    for (int i=1;i<=bound;i++){
         String data = ???????????;
         if (data == "connected" || data == "disconnected") then {
            System.out.println(data);
         }else if(?????==2){// to check how many strings there is, if it's ["abc","def"] or ["abc"]
            String data2 = ??????????????;
            System.out.println(data+" says: "+data2);
         }else{
            //something else
         }
    };

}
```

What should I insert to these parts with question marks to make code work?

I cannot find any way to make it work...

*Sorry for my bad English.*

**EDIT:** Changed response to `[["connected"], ["user1","Hello"], ["user2","Hey"], ["disconnected"]]`. Earlier response was not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The response that you have pasted is not a valid json. paste it in http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ and see the error.

Please find the below code snippet:

public static void printEvents(String id) 
{
        String response = "[[\"connected\"] ,[\"user1:Hello\"],[\"user2:Hey\"],[\"disconnected\"]]";

```
    JsonElement parse = (new JsonParser()).parse(response); //found this in internet


    int bound = ((JsonArray)parse).size(); // Should be 4

    for (int i = 0; i < bound; i++) {
        String data = ((JsonArray)parse).get(0).getAsString();
        if (data.equals("connected") || data.equals("disconnected")) {
            System.out.println(data);
            continue;
        }
        String[] splittedData = data.split(":");
        if (splittedData.length
                == 2) {// to check how many strings there is, if it's ["abc","def"] or ["abc"]
            System.out.println(splittedData[0] + " says: " + splittedData[1]);
        }
        /*
        *else{
        * your else logic goes here
        * }
         *  */
    }

}
```

Couple of suggestions:

1. If you are new to json world, use jackson instead of Gson.
2. the response is not a good design. Slightly correct json:

{
  "firstKey": "connected",
  "userResponses": [
    {
      "user1": "hey"
    },
    {
      "user2": "hi"
    }
  ],
  "lastKey": "disconnected"
}

3. Also try to define pojos , instead of working inline with json.

Comment: Response is `[["connected"] ,["user1":"Hello"],["user2":"Hey"],["disconnected"]]`
Your response `[["connected"] ,["user1:Hello"],["user2:Hey"],["disconnected"]]`

Your code works, but when I change response to correct one, it doesn't work. `com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at line 1 column 26 path $[1][1]`

Comment: The response you are saying is not even a valid json. In json inside an array you can't have entry like < "user1":"Hello">. If you want in the same structure , you should change your response format. I have given one possible format above. Another format that you can look for:
[["connected"] ,[{"user1":"Hello"}],[{"user2":"Hey"}],["disconnected"]]

Comment: I got it working. Thank you very much, I changed it to `[["connected"] ,["user1","Hello"],["user2","Hey"],["disconnected"]]` to make it valid json.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a separate class like this:

```
class MyClass{
String name;
String value;
}
```

and then:

```
List<MyClass> myclasses = new Gson().fromJson(response, new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>(){}.getType());
```

then

```
for(MyClass myclass: myclasses){
...
}
```